# Forbid files by extension in Windows 7/8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, firewall, group-policy

I want to forbid following actions on Windows 7/8:

1. Zip and 7Zip archives  to be unpacked/executed , especially when it's a self-extracting archives
2. Exe files to be run
3. dll files

Any mentioned forbidden extensions should be prohibited to be downloaded by mail clients and/or

So that that users without my permission could not execute exe files, add some unknown drivers to the laptop, even if they have already got it by email in outlook.

I am thinking also of a software, which could make that thing on or off.

If for exe files it's about to setup group policy, how to do it with archives and other extensions? Lets after a while I want to add to forbid list some other extensions?

Comment: for a: for all installed applications that can open archives , eg 7Zip, WinZip, WinRar, locate them in explorer, then right_click->Properties->Compatibility->Change Setting for all users->Select Run this program as an administrator.

Comment: why? I want to FORBID not to allow.

Comment: because, if done so, any user without administrative privilege  will not be able to open archive. When he tries to open it, he will be prompted for a password. You can verify it by doing as i said in your administrator account and opening an archive in guest account

Comment: Filtering on extension is weak security. Your users will simply rename the file and mail it with the new name (E.g. file.zip.txt). ON the same note: Do not bother with the mail part. Block it at the OS level or even block all programs except white listed ones (windows can do that).

Comment: What do you mean by "forbid dll files" exactly? Are you talking about shell extensions?

Comment: yes, driver files and extensions....

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a standalone laptop. You might want to consider a steady-state like solution. The original MS SteadyState tool allowed you to set which users can run which applications and open which kinds of files. Also it would allow to block or roll back any changes made by users.

Unfortunatly Microsoft has not provided a SteadyState version for MS Windows 7 and newer. MS does offer a rather involved 90+ pages whitepaper to reach a similiar result with built in system services, most prominently GPs. You can read about and download the whitepaper from MS site: http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/springboard/archive/2010/09/27/steady-state-for-windows-7.aspx

My suggestion, however, would be to take a look at 3rd party products, such as Deep Freeze or RestoreRX. For private single place usage some of these solutions are even free.